# Limits on Apex invocations from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, limits

Is there a limit on how many times LWC can call an `@AuraEnabled` action and Apex controller? (Provided we do not get into the long-running Apex issues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both lightning components and apex are in-house platforms although the connection between them is asynchronous and so you have the scope to directly import apex method definitions. So this will not hamper the performance of other orgs sharing resources and so no limits are enforced. If it was an external system there would have been limits as it would have hampered ability of other orgs sharing resources.

**TESTING:**
Created below apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string getSample(String st){
    return 'sample '+st;
}
```

And implement below in JS:

```
i = 0;
connectedCallback() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.i++;
        console.log('sending ', this.i);
        getSample({ st: 'int' + this.i }).then((resp) => console.log(resp)).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }, 0);
}
```

This has successfully run for more than 100,000 times in few minutes (However you can test for more number of times). I thinks its practically impossible to have more than 10,000 apex calls per user in a day considering many invocations on keyup.

Comment: Hmmm but i can get my users to press buttons calling my apex millions of times from LWC? So if i stay within governor limits on allocations, and performance, the users can use a lot Apex capacity?

Comment: adding the info in answer above

Comment: @zaitsman There is caching and boxcar effects that prevent a large number of transactions from occurring at once. You would have to intentionally craft a component that defeats these mechanisms in order to even have a chance of being denied access to resources. Any normal amount of user activity would be allowed.

Comment: @sfdcfox By using above I observed that only about few 10s of calls are boxcarred every few ms and the results have been returned in same way. Can you pls suggest any improvement in testing methodology?

Comment: @sfdcfox i thought that with `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)` each call is a true APEX call?

Comment: @zaitsman Yes and no. While each would be an Apex call, the server itself would only be hit a few times per second because of the boxcar effect, even if you basically just wrote an infinite loop to hammer the server as fast as you can. In fact, at some point, the client would probably just end up with a full queue of waiting Apex calls and the UI would become unresponsive or sluggish. Also, a typical user can only click their mouse or keyboard buttons perhaps 20 times per second, a physical limitation of the human body, not nearly the "millions" of clicks you'd imagine.

Comment: @sfdcfox considering this is unlimited, how is the platform protected against automation via APEX/LWC invocations? e.g. normal REST APIs have limits; but if i simply write a Selenium script or something similar to manipulate the browser, i can fully automate loading data through this unlimited entry point

Comment: @zaitsman It's my understanding that there are no hard limits, but there are monitoring alarms that will trigger if a subscriber uses too many resources. This may result in throttling, additional service fees, or discontinuation of the subscriber's use of the platform. The public information is intentionally vague so as to avoid clients gaming the system. However, the limits are reasonably high, and few clients ever reach a point where this happens. As long as you're not intentionally trying a Denial of Service (DOS) attack, you should be okay in normal use cases.

Comment: @zaitsman A Selenium script to load a million records might even still be fair use, or you could even write an import wizard using VF, Aura, or LWC, and it would probably sail by just fine.